# Calculate electric field of a charged annulus

Tags: python, python-2.x, scipy

This script calculates the shape of the electric field on a 2D grid perpendicular to a uniformly charged annulus using SciPy's `dblquad` ([tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html), [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html)).

I've chosen a coarse grid and specified a very large relative error `epsrel` here so that this example will run in about 10 seconds, but I'll be using it on a much finer grid and with much lower specified error.

I'd like to know if there are ways this can be significantly sped up without loss of accuracy, which should be in the 1E-7 neighborhood.

I'll be avoiding pathological points manually, as I've done here by avoiding the z=0 plane. I've left out constants and units to reduce clutter.

[image]

```
def Excalc(r, th):
    x, y, z = r*np.cos(th), r*np.sin(th), 0.0
    return (x0-x) * ((x0-x)**2 + (y0-y)**2 + (z0-z)**2)**-1.5

def Eycalc(r, th):
    x, y, z = r*np.cos(th), r*np.sin(th), 0.0
    return (y0-y) * ((x0-x)**2 + (y0-y)**2 + (z0-z)**2)**-1.5

def Ezcalc(r, th):
    x, y, z = r*np.cos(th), r*np.sin(th), 0.0
    return (z0-z) * ((x0-x)**2 + (y0-y)**2 + (z0-z)**2)**-1.5


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

twopi = 2.*np.pi

# annulus of uniform, unit charge density
rmin, rmax   = 0.8, 1.2
thmin, thmax = 0,   twopi

x = np.arange(-2,    2.1, 0.1)
z = np.arange(-1.55, 1.6, 0.1) # avoid z=0 plane for integration.
X, Z = np.meshgrid(x, z)
s = X.shape

eps = 1E-4
y0  = 0

fields, errors = [], []
for x0, z0 in zip(X.flatten(), Z.flatten()):
    # use of lambda in lieu of function calls https://stackoverflow.com/a/49441680/3904031
    Ex, Exerr  = dblquad(Excalc, thmin, thmax, lambda t: rmin, lambda t: rmax, epsrel=eps)
    Ey, Eyerr  = dblquad(Eycalc, thmin, thmax, lambda t: rmin, lambda t: rmax, epsrel=eps)
    Ez, Ezerr  = dblquad(Ezcalc, thmin, thmax, lambda t: rmin, lambda t: rmax, epsrel=eps)
    fields.append([Ex, Ey, Ez])
    errors.append([Exerr, Eyerr, Ezerr])

Evec = np.stack([np.array(thing).reshape(s) for thing in zip(*fields)])
Emag = np.sqrt((Evec**2).sum(axis=0))

Evecerr = np.stack([np.array(thing).reshape(s) for thing in zip(*errors)])
Emagerr = np.sqrt((Evecerr**2).sum(axis=0))

if True:
    names = 'Ex', 'Ey', 'Ez', 'Emag'
    plt.figure()
    for i, (E, name) in enumerate(zip([e for e in Evec] + [Emag], names)):
        smalls = np.abs(E) < 1E-08
        E[smalls] = 0.     # fudge to keep Ey from showing 1E-14 fields
        plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
        plt.imshow(E, origin='lower')
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.title(name, fontsize=16)
    plt.show()

if True:
    names = 'Ex rel error', 'Ey rel error', 'Ez rel error', 'Emag rel error'
    plt.figure()
    for i, (err, name) in enumerate(zip([er for er in Evecerr] + [Emagerr], names)):
        plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
        plt.imshow(err/E, origin='lower')
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.title(name, fontsize=16)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main time consuming factor here is calculating the `dbquad`, that said there are some smaller improvements you can make

## split into functions

lookup of local variables in a function is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12590209/1562285) than a global lookup, so putthing each part in a function can speed up this process already. If you do this, beware that your `E_calc` functions use global state (`x0`, `y0` and `z0`), so they should be defined in the function scope, so they can use the local variables

## numpy

You can use `numpy` a bit more to assemble the final answers

Instead of  keeping 2 arrays `fields` and `errors`, you can  keep this in 1 array, and index the errors and values.

```
def calc2():
    twopi = 2.*np.pi

    # annulus of uniform, unit charge density
    rmin, rmax   = 0.8, 1.2
    thmin, thmax = 0,   twopi

    x = np.arange(-2,    2.1, 0.1)
    z = np.arange(-1.55, 1.6, 0.1) # avoid z=0 plane for integration.
    X, Z = np.meshgrid(x, z)
    s = X.shape

    eps = 1E-4
    y0  = 0
    def Excalc(r, th):
        x, y, z = r*np.cos(th), r*np.sin(th), 0.0
        return (x0-x) * ((x0-x)**2 + (y0-y)**2 + (z0-z)**2)**-1.5

    def Eycalc(r, th):
        x, y, z = r*np.cos(th), r*np.sin(th), 0.0
        return (y0-y) * ((x0-x)**2 + (y0-y)**2 + (z0-z)**2)**-1.5

    def Ezcalc(r, th):
        x, y, z = r*np.cos(th), r*np.sin(th), 0.0
        return (z0-z) * ((x0-x)**2 + (y0-y)**2 + (z0-z)**2)**-1.5
    values = []
    for x0, z0 in zip(X.flatten(), Z.flatten()):
        # use of lambda in lieu of function calls https://stackoverflow.com/a/49441680/3904031
        Ex, Exerr  = dblquad(Excalc, thmin, thmax, lambda t: rmin, lambda t: rmax, epsrel=eps)
        Ey, Eyerr  = dblquad(Eycalc, thmin, thmax, lambda t: rmin, lambda t: rmax, epsrel=eps)
        Ez, Ezerr  = dblquad(Ezcalc, thmin, thmax, lambda t: rmin, lambda t: rmax, epsrel=eps)
        values.append([Ex, Ey, Ez, Exerr, Eyerr, Ezerr])
#         errors.append([Exerr, Eyerr, Ezerr])
    values = np.array(values).T.reshape(6, *X.shape)

    e_vec = values[:3]
    e_mag = np.linalg.norm(e_vec, axis=0)

    e_vec_err = values[3:]
    e_mag_err = np.linalg.norm(e_vec_err, axis=0)

    return Evec, Emag, Evecerr, Emagerr
```

This resulted in a very slight reduction in time, so will not save you heaps

## lru_cache

refactoring the `calc` methods to reuse the most of the result actually slowed things down, this is how I tackled that

```
from functools import partial, lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def calc(r, th, coords_0):
    coords_0 = np.array(coords_0)
    diff = coords_0 - np.array((r*np.cos(th), r*np.sin(th), 0.0))
    return diff * ((diff)**2).sum()**-1.5

def calc3():
    rmin, rmax = 0.8, 1.2
    thmin, thmax = 0, 2.*np.pi

#     s = X.shape

    eps = 1E-4
    y0  = 0
    x = np.arange(-2,    2.1, 0.2)
    z = np.arange(-1.55, 1.6, 0.2) # avoid z=0 plane for integration.
    X, Z = np.meshgrid(x, z)

    calc_axis = lambda r, th, coords_0, axis: calc(r, th, coords_0)[axis]

    values = []
    for x0, z0 in zip(X.flatten(), Z.flatten()):
        coords_0 = (x0, y0, z0)
        Excalc, Eycalc, Ezcalc = (partial(calc_axis, coords_0=coords_0, axis=i) for i in range(3))
        # use of lambda in lieu of function calls https://stackoverflow.com/a/49441680/3904031
        Ex, Exerr  = dblquad(Excalc, thmin, thmax, lambda t: rmin, lambda t: rmax, epsrel=eps)
        Ey, Eyerr  = dblquad(Eycalc, thmin, thmax, lambda t: rmin, lambda t: rmax, epsrel=eps)
        Ez, Ezerr  = dblquad(Ezcalc, thmin, thmax, lambda t: rmin, lambda t: rmax, epsrel=eps)
        values.append((Ex, Ey, Ez, Exerr, Eyerr, Ezerr))
    print(calc.cache_info())
    values = np.array(values).T.reshape(6, *X.shape)

    e_vec = values[:3]
    e_mag = np.linalg.norm(e_vec, axis=0)

    e_vec_err = values[3:]
    e_mag_err = np.linalg.norm(e_vec_err, axis=0)
    return e_vec, e_mag, e_vec_err, e_mag_err, values
```

Apparently, about halve of the calls to `calc` were cached, but moving the calculation to this method resulted in a net slowdown.

## numba

What did result in a speed increase was [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/)

just adding `@jit` before `def calc(r, th, coords_0):` made the calculation 3 times as fast

Comment: Okay, this is great! I will certainly give this a try! It's late here so will test tomorrow. Does "3 times as fast" apply to the whole thing? I've assumed that `dblquad` is already compiled, so `@jit` would not be affecting the actual numerical integration time, would it?

Comment: i haven't tried `@jit` in front of the main routine, just before the smaller `calc` routine. But since that one gets executed millions of times while calculating the `dblquad`, that speeds up the program dramatically

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean now, and of course it makes sense! Okay i"ll give  it a try soon, thanks!

Comment: Great! original: 42 sec, lookup & better numpification: 32 sec, add `@jit`: 8 sec. Okay there is quite a lot I can learn here in just this one answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the case, but if any of the 'calc' functions are ever called more than once with the same `r` and `th` values, then `functools.lru_cache` could help speed things up here.

This is used to decorate a method, and then it stores a cache of the results for each set of params - returning the cached result immediately rather than re-running the calculation.  It does require more memory to store the results, however, so you have to consider if that trade-off is acceptable.

You *might* be able to gain some speed by merging the main part of these methods, and then returning `x`, `y`, `z` and the 'calculation' result. This is more likely to 'hit' the cache since you now have 1 cache, not 3. A simplified example here:

```
@functools.lru_cache()
def Ecalc(r, th):
    x, y, z = r*np.cos(th), r*np.sin(th), 0.0
    return x, y, z, ((x0-x)**2 + (y0-y)**2 + (z0-z)**2)**-1.5

# Maybe also lru_cache decorator here?
def new_method(axis, r, th):
    x, y, z, result = Ecalc(r, th)
    axes = {'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z}
    index = axes[axis]
    return (index0 - index) * result

new_method('x', r, th)
```

Comment: I see. I think it would be quite infrequent for the `dblquad` to call the exact same floats very often considering how it works, but I will give this a try because it looks like something very useful and good to know about. If I don't see a large change in performance, is there some simple way to add a counter to see how often the `lru_cache` is actually used?

Comment: @uhoh: The [documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache): "the wrapped function is instrumented with a `cache_info()` function that returns a named tuple showing *hits*, *misses*, *maxsize* and *currsize*". So have a look at `Ecalc.cache_info()`. (But I doubt a cache will be useful.)

Comment: beware that `x0`, and `z0` change every iteration